# SQL Condition With Multiple Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table which shows me my users' downloads reports.
The table looks like this:

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║ url        ║ user        ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ Bla        ║ 1           ║
║ 2 ║ Bla Bla    ║ 1           ║
║ 3 ║ Bla Bla Bla║ 1           ║
║ 4 ║ Bla2       ║ 2           ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

If I want to select the user that downloaded the url `Bla`, I just do:

```
SELECT `user` FROM `links` WHERE `url` = 'Bla'
```

But I want to select the user that downloaded `Bla` **and** downloaded `Bla Bla` too.

How can I do that?

Thank you, and sorry for my English.

Comment: @bluefeet Just for example

Comment: Added the answer. Let me know if you need anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `WHERE` clause with a combination of `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to get the result:

```
select user
from yourtable
where url in ('Bla', 'Bla Bla')
group by user
having count(distinct url) = 2;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c218/2)

Comment: dammit, beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self join

```
select u.user
from links u
join links u1 on(u.`user`=u1.user)
where u1.url ='Bla'
and u.url= 'Bla Bla'
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/daa6a6/1)

Comment: Awesome solution! this is the *only answer that works if multiple users have the conditions.* Can you explain it a little more on what a self join is and how does this work? Thanks

Comment: Oh, my bad, but this works for only two `WHERE`s (conditions) is there a workaround for this limitation? -Thanks agin

Comment: @Webinan my previous comment was missing 4 in having clause ,yes it will work for only 2 conditions and if there are many then this technique will be ugly to have as many where and as many self joins for the good one you should look at bluefeet's answer again you need to provide the count of your conditions lets say you need for 4 users then where 4 conditions and having clause becomes having count(distinct url) = 4;

Answer (score 0):

[**<kbd>The sqlfiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e3a2/1)

```
select 
  user, 
  group_concat(url) as urls 
from 
  links
where 
  url in ('Bla', 'Bla Bla') -- add your urls here
group by user
having count(distinct url) > 1;
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**`For non-MYSQL`**

```
SELECT DISTINCT `user` FROM `links` WHERE `url`='Bla'
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT `user` FROM `links` WHERE `url`='Bla Bla';

OR
```

**For MYSQL**

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.x AS Users_Bla_BlaBla
FROM 
( SELECT DISTINCT `user` AS x FROM `links` WHERE `url`='Bla' ) a 
INNER JOIN 
( SELECT DISTINCT `user` AS Y FROM `links` WHERE `url`='Bla Bla' ) b 
USING (x,y);
```

Comment: That will only get him users that downloaded either one of those urls... he wants users that have downloaded both.

Comment: This way still has the disadvantage of needing a new intersect each time another url needs to be added to the mix.  bluefeet's answer seems better...